# Selecting YYYYMM of the previous month in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am using Hive, so the SQL syntax might be slightly different. How do I get the data from the previous month? For example, if today is 2015-04-30, I need the data from March in this format 201503? Thanks!

```
select 
    employee_id, hours,
    previous_month_date--YYYYMM,
from 
    employees 
where 
    previous_month_date = cast(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') as int)
```

Comment: Another possible idea, I append to where clause. However it works for current month, but not previous month. Also, adding 0 only helps for the 1 digit month like 01, 02, 03...etc, I think for month 10, 11, 12...etc shows up as 010, 011, 012. I am trying avoid this:    cast(concat(year(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')),
              0,month(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))) as int);

Comment: what happens if the date is `2015-07-31`.  There is no june 31st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `(year('2015-04-30')*100+month('2015-04-30'))-1` for the above mentioned date, it will return `201503` or something like `(year(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()))*100+month(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())))-1` for today's previous month. Assuming your date column is in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format you can use the first example and substitute the date string with your table column name; for any other format the second example will do, add the column name in the `unix_timestamp()` operator.

Answer (score 2):

From experience, it's safer to use *DATE_ADD(Today, -1-Day(Today))* to compute last-day-of-previous-month without having to worry about edge cases. From there you can do what you want e.g.

```
select
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as TODAY,
  date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), -1-cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'd') as int)) as LAST_DAY_PREV_MONTH,
  substr(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), -1-cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'd') as int)), 1,7) as PREV_MONTH,
  cast(substr(regexp_replace(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), -1-cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'd') as int)), '-',''), 1,6) as int) as PREV_MONTH_NUM
from WHATEVER limit 1

-- today       last_day_prev_month  prev_month  prev_month_num
-- 2015-08-13  2015-07-30           2015-07             201507
```

See Hive documentation about [date functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions), [string functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) etc.

Answer (score 2):

below works across year boundaries w/o complex calcs:

`date_format(add_months(current_date, -1), 'yyyyMM')` --previous month's yyyyMM

in general,

`date_format(add_months(current_date, -n), 'yyyyMM')` --previous n-th month's yyyyMM

use proper sign for needed direction (back/ahead)

Answer (score 1):

Angelo's reply is a good start but it returns 201500 if the original date was 2015-01-XX. Building on his answer, I suggest using the following:

```
IF(month(${DATE}) = 1,
    (year(${DATE})-1)*100 + 12,
    year(${DATE})*100 + month(${DATE})-1
) as month_key
```

Answer (score 0):

provided you get rid of those hyphens in your input string , previous date's month id in YYYYMM format you can get by:-

```
select if(  ((${hiveconf:MonthId}-1)%100)=0  ,${hiveconf:MonthId}-89,${hiveconf:MonthId}-1  ) as PreviousMonthId;
```